# SSL PROBLEMS WITH Polish liters

Tags: tomcat, grails, ssl

I'm quite strange problem . I have written applications in Grails / Groovy (J2EE ) . Tomcata7 using . The application uses the transmission and display of data via json . The problem is that when exposed http application is running and when it's ok to show Apke to https is my application does not include Polish characters eg within the search criteria thus does not return a value as it is at http

Comment: what is missing?  only the char or does it fail by other means? what charset are you using (what charset does work on regular http)?

Comment: Hi. I use UTF -8 in my APP. When I use of a filter with Polish characters does not return anything in https but in http is ok

Comment: and it returns a regular result, if your result does not contain such chars?

Comment: Is exactly as you write ? What could be the problem in https ?